# How to build ASP.NET Core 2.0 application on Windows?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Recently I installed new Visual Studio 2017 and updated SDK and Runtime to latest version 2.0 then created new ASP.NET Core 2.0 project (before all this steps I uninstall VS 2015). After all I was not able to build project, always got the same error.

**Used tools:**

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 Version **15.3.5**
- ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017 **15.0.30726.0**
- ASP.NET Core Razor Language Services **1.0**
- ASP.NET Template Engine 2017 **15.0.30726.0**
- NuGet Package Manager **4.3.1**
- SQL Server Data Tools **15.1.61707.200**

And of course I have the latest SDK and Runtime installed

_

**Error:**

```
[22:57:51]
[22:57:51]Errors in C:\path\to\project\Server\Server.csproj
[22:57:51]    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.0.0 is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
[22:57:51]    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.0.0 is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
[22:57:51]    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2.
[22:57:51]    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.0.0 is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2) / win7-x86. Package Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
[22:57:51]    Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.0.0 is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2) / win7-x86. Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
[22:57:51]    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2 (win7-x86).
[22:57:51]
[22:57:51]Errors in C:\path\to\project\Server\Server.csproj
[22:57:51]    Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
[22:57:51]    Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Contracts 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Contracts 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
[22:57:51]    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0.
[22:57:51]Process exited with code 1
```

Comment: Can you paste the xml from your Server.csproj file?

Comment: My Server.csproj 
`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>`

Comment: Have you tried doing building a console app with "dotnet new console" just to level set things?

Comment: When I use 'dotnet new console' and then 'dotnet run' console app run successfully